# Efficiency of PVectors vs two separate variables in Processing.js

Tags: processing, processing.js

I was creating two arrays to hold x and y values for points I want to draw. As I was doing this, I remembered the PVectors I had recently learned about, and instead created a single array of PVectors instead of the two I had originally. Which method is more efficient and will result in less browser lag given a large set of x and y values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try both and find out? Create an array of 1,000 `PVectors`, and compare that to creating arrays with 1,000 `float` values. Increase that to 10,000, or 100,000, or 1,000,000.

Display the `frameRate` variable on the screen in each case. (Don't use `println()`, it's way too slow- use the `text()` function instead!) When do you notice it start to drop?

This might seem like I'm answering your question with a question, but the best way to answer questions about performance is to just try it yourself, do some benchmarking and profiling, and decide what's best in your specific context.

But I would doubt that you're going to notice a huge difference in either case. The speed is probably identical. The only difference you might notice is that using `PVector` will probably use a little bit more memory. But again, probably not enough to really care about.

Instead of worrying about this kind of optimization (which is a premature optimization, or a micro-optimization), you should just use whichever approach makes the most sense to you. Code readability and maintainability are more important than little things like this, so just use whichever seems more logical in your program.

Comment: I followed your advice, and created such a program. What I found was that if I didn't limit the number of x and y values, after three minutes, my frame rate in both cases dropped from 60 to below thirty. The PVector array was about three frames faster after three minutes. Here's where things get interesting. With a limit of 200 imposed, neither method faltered or lagged and stayed more or less at 60 frames per second. However, when I imposed a limit of 2000, the PVector array dragged the frame rate to 40 frames per second after three minutes, while the 2 arrays didn't falter and stayed at 60.

Comment: @EmmaCooper I'd be curious to see your code. Why is your lag getting worse over time?

Comment: I could explain it, but I think it'd be easier to just show you. Here's a link: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/lissajous-curve/4879969070481408

Comment: @EmmaCooper Interesting, thanks for the link. The reason I'm confused is this: if you limit the number of objects to 2000, then the maximum objects you'll have is 2000. It's not like you'll have more than 2000 objects after 3 minutes, or 10 minutes, or 24 hours. So it seems weird that it's getting slower over time.

Comment: Sorry, could have clarified what I meant. With a limit of 2000, the PVector frame rate only slowed to 40, but once it reached 40, it stayed there. The array frame rate never left 60. Both of those values make sense to me. Do they sound right to you?